# How to find all overlapping phrases between two strings, in Java?

Tags: java, string, string-matching

Assume that I have two strings

1. I like chicken salad, it's my favorite food.
2. This book contains tons of recipes on making all sorts of food, including cakes, chicken salad, etc.

Here the overlapping phrases between the two strings are - chicken, salad, chicken salad, food.

What's the best way to find the overlapping phrases between two strings? Assume that both are syntax and semantics clean, and also the first one is always quite shorter than the second one.

Comment: You could create a hash of the words in the shorter string, and then check each word of the second against the first, or just plug every word into the hash and if it finds one use that to show that it overlaps

Comment: I would tokenize the short string and search in the long string. On a side note, you should consider using an additional stop word list to ignore searching common words like the, to, at, it etc.,

Comment: if any possible substring of the shorter string is to be found in the longer string, that would generate a helluva lot of tokens

Comment: Is there a library out there does the tokenize of a string? and for the first string, I assume the partial tokenized result would include 'chicken', 'chicken salad', 'favorite food', 'food' etc...

Comment: @MattCoubrough, I would also expect that the 'noise' words like 'I', 'the', 'my', etc should be removed as well when doing tokenize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this approach. Seems to suffice your need of `salad, chicken, chicken salad, food` as overlapping phrases.

```
public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException{
    String firstSentence = "I like chicken salad, it's my favorite food";
    String secondSentence = "This book contains tons of recipes on making all sorts of food, including cakes, chicken salad, etc";
    String[] firstSentenceWords = firstSentence.replaceAll("[.,]", "").split(" ");
    Set<String> overlappingPhrases = new HashSet<String>();     
    String lastPhrase = "";     
    for(String word : firstSentenceWords){
        if(lastPhrase.isEmpty()){
            lastPhrase = word;
        }else{
            lastPhrase = lastPhrase + " " + word;
        }
        if(secondSentence.contains(word)){
            overlappingPhrases.add(word);
            if(secondSentence.contains(lastPhrase)){
                overlappingPhrases.add(lastPhrase);
            }
        }else{
            lastPhrase = "";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(overlappingPhrases);
}
```

`overlappingPhrases` set contains `[chicken salad, chicken, salad, food]`

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

**

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    String one = "I like chicken salad, it's my favorite food.";
    String result = one.replaceAll("[.,]","");
    String[] tokens = result.split(" ");
    String second = "This book contains tons of recipes on making all sorts of food, including cakes, chicken salad, etc.";
    System.out.println(result);
    for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++){
        if(second.indexOf(tokens[i])>=0){
            al.add(tokens[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(al);
    }
```

**

Comment: It's the same algorithm as what @thinkinjava explained, it won't work as it can't return me 'chicken salad'...

Answer (score 0):

first, i think you can use the Brute-Force Algorithm. you can spilt the word in the shor string and you also spilt the word in the long string like this:

```
String short_words[] = short_string.spilt(" ");
String long_words[] = long_string.spilt(" ");
```

next you can iterator the words in the short_words array.and check every word Whether in the long_words array.but the time Complexity is so bad that is 0(m * n).
second, i think you can use the hash function to do this.

Comment: But the brute-force algorithm won't return me 'chicken salad', but instead 'chicken', 'salad', ...

Answer (score 0):

An approach to your requirement:

```
public static void overlappingPhrases() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String string1 = "I like chicken salad, it's my favorite food.";
    String string2 = "This book contains tons of recipes on making all sorts of food, including cakes, chicken salad, etc.";
    String[] words = string1.replaceAll("[.,]","").split(" ");
    System.out.println(string1+"\n"+string2);
    for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
        if(string2.indexOf(words[i])>=0){
            list.add(words[i]);     
            int j=i;
            String tmp=words[i];
            while(j+1<words.length){
                if(string2.indexOf(tmp + " " + words[++j])>=0)
                   tmp = tmp + " " + words[j]; 
                else {
                    if (!tmp.equals(words[i]))
                        list.add(tmp);                         
                    break;
                }
            }                        
         }                            
    }
    System.out.println("Overlapping phrases: "+list);
}
```

Output:

```
[chicken, chicken salad, salad, food]
```

Comment: like the idea, though the O complexity seems not low.